# How to decrypt inaccessible Windows 7 drive

Tags: windows-7, disk-encryption

I was in the process of encrypting my hard drive (which I have done multiple times in the past) with DiskCryptor when I suddenly needed to shut down my laptop. I clicked on pause (which has always protected me in the past) and then shut down my laptop (it was about 50% done). Now when I attempt to turn it on, I get a windows boot error, and the windows recovery disk doesn't recognize the installation. Is there any way to decrypt this or somehow bypass the encryption? Thanks!

Comment: You don't have a diskcryptor rescue disk?

Answer (score 2):

"As DiskCryptor's makers suggest, you should create a bootable Windows disk (LiveCD) with DiskCryptor, using the company's instructions, before encrypting your Windows drive. That way, if you run into booting problems later, you can insert the disc and use the included DiskCryptor utility to decrypt the drive with your password. (If you don't perform this step, you won't be able to retrieve your files.) You could use a different PC to create this bootable disc later, if you run into booting problems, but it's wiser to create it ahead of time so that you'll have it on hand when the need arises."

But it appears the [wiki page that had the instructions](https://diskcryptor.net/wiki/LiveCD/en) on how to make a rescue disk has been deleted.

You can try to use the [wayback machine](https://web.archive.org/web/*/https://diskcryptor.net/wiki/LiveCD/en) to view a copy of the page

Comment: I ended up just re-installing the OS because I found I had made an external backup a couple days ago. Thanks for the suggestion though!